# While portion of udevadm list do I capture for rules

Tags: usb, symlink, udev, serial-port

I did:

```
udevadm info -a -n /dev/ttyUSB0
```

as I'm trying to make a symlink rule for an arduino.  The problem is, I'm not sure which of the sections in the output to use for the rules.  The first time I did a rule for it, it worked great, I grabbed the SUBSYSTEMS, DRIVER, ATTRS{idVendor} for the one I thought was it, it was, reloaded the rules and it worked.  When I restarted, the symlink didn't work -- I checked in and the section I had used had idVendor missing -- it was there on a parent, but not in the same section with the same SUBSYSTEMS and DRIVER.  So, which of these do I use to uniquely identify my Arduino for a rule to symlink the serial port?

```
looking at device '/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/ttyUSB0/tty/ttyUSB0':
    KERNEL=="ttyUSB0"
    SUBSYSTEM=="tty"
    DRIVER==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/ttyUSB0':
    KERNELS=="ttyUSB0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb-serial"
    DRIVERS=="ch341-uart"
    ATTRS{port_number}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0':
    KERNELS=="1-1.3:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="ch341"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="ff"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="01"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="02"
    ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="03"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"
    ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3':
    KERNELS=="1-1.3"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1.3"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1a86"
    ATTRS{speed}=="12"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="8"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="4"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="96mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="80"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0254"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{version}==" 1.10"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="62"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{removable}=="removable"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="7523"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="ff"
    ATTRS{product}=="USB2.0-Serial"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1':
    KERNELS=="1-1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="02"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="0424"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="2"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="2mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="5"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0200"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="57"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="9514"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1':
    KERNELS=="usb1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="1"
    ATTRS{interface_authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0404"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{serial}=="3f980000.usb"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="25"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 4.4.13-v7+ dwc_otg_hcd"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{product}=="DWC OTG Controller"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb':
    KERNELS=="3f980000.usb"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="platform"
    DRIVERS=="dwc_otg"
    ATTRS{hnp}=="HstNegScs = 0x0"
    ATTRS{srp}=="SesReqScs = 0x1"
    ATTRS{regvalue}=="invalid offset"
    ATTRS{hsic_connect}=="HSIC Connect = 0x1"
    ATTRS{guid}=="GUID = 0x2708a000"
    ATTRS{mode}=="Mode = 0x1"
    ATTRS{srpcapable}=="SRPCapable = 0x1"
    ATTRS{regdump}=="Register Dump"
    ATTRS{gpvndctl}=="GPVNDCTL = 0x00000000"
    ATTRS{ggpio}=="GGPIO = 0x00000000"
    ATTRS{hprt0}=="HPRT0 = 0x00001005"
    ATTRS{wr_reg_test}=="Time to write GNPTXFSIZ reg 10000000 times: 360 msecs (36 jiffies)"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{hcd_frrem}=="HCD Dump Frame Remaining"
    ATTRS{mode_ch_tim_en}=="Mode Change Ready Timer Enable = 0x0"
    ATTRS{gnptxfsiz}=="GNPTXFSIZ = 0x01000306"
    ATTRS{remote_wakeup}=="Remote Wakeup Sig = 0 Enabled = 0 LPM Remote Wakeup = 0"
    ATTRS{busconnected}=="Bus Connected = 0x1"
    ATTRS{hcddump}=="HCD Dump"
    ATTRS{gotgctl}=="GOTGCTL = 0x001c0001"
    ATTRS{spramdump}=="SPRAM Dump"
    ATTRS{grxfsiz}=="GRXFSIZ = 0x00000306"
    ATTRS{gsnpsid}=="GSNPSID = 0x4f54280a"
    ATTRS{gusbcfg}=="GUSBCFG = 0x20001700"
    ATTRS{hptxfsiz}=="HPTXFSIZ = 0x02000406"
    ATTRS{devspeed}=="Device Speed = 0x0"
    ATTRS{fr_interval}=="Frame Interval = 0x1d4c"
    ATTRS{rem_wakeup_pwrdn}==""
    ATTRS{bussuspend}=="Bus Suspend = 0x0"
    ATTRS{buspower}=="Bus Power = 0x1"
    ATTRS{hnpcapable}=="HNPCapable = 0x1"
    ATTRS{rd_reg_test}=="Time to read GNPTXFSIZ reg 10000000 times: 980 msecs (98 jiffies)"
    ATTRS{enumspeed}=="Device Enumeration Speed = 0x1"
    ATTRS{inv_sel_hsic}=="Invert Select HSIC = 0x0"
    ATTRS{regoffset}=="0xffffffff"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/soc':
    KERNELS=="soc"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="platform"
    DRIVERS==""
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform':
    KERNELS=="platform"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically I use `idVendor` and `idProduct`

eg for my OpenLogic Sniffer I have:

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="04d8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="fc92", MODE="0666", SYMLINK+="OpenLogicSniffer"
```

For my Arduinos I just use the `idVendor` to set the mode; I don't create a symlink

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="16d0", MODE="0666"
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1a86", MODE="0666"
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2341", MODE="0666"
```

Similarly, for my Altera Blaster I want it to be visible to my VirtualBox instance so I have

```
ATTR{idVendor}=="09fb", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6001", GROUP="vboxusers"
```

These values are easy to get from `lsusb`

eg

```
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 2341:0043 Arduino SA Uno R3 (CDC ACM)
```

And we can see the device:

```
% ls -l /dev/ttyACM0 
crw-rw-rw- 1 root dialout 166, 0 Aug  2 14:28 /dev/ttyACM0
```